# ADO to query MDB and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ado

I've got a database that resides on an `SQL serve`r box, and another in a separate `mdb file`.

Both contain similar data, but I'd like to run a query that checks unmatched records from a field that exists in both.

Is this something that's easy enough to do using `ADO` (`VBA`)?  If so can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you move the MDB file to the SQL server?  It's a lot easier to do this if you can actually attach the file and reference it as a real database.  Or even create a local SQL Server instance with it, and create a linked server from one to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to create a new Access Database or ADP, and link the tables from both the SQL server and the other MDB. That way you've got an interface to both from within the same instance, which allows you to query or join different tables.